# services scheme diagram

Tags: web-server, schema

We have many web-services, applications and sites that are hosted on 4 different server farms, multiple urls, A records, sub-domains, HTTP redirects and more.

What is the best way to start and create a readable diagram/scheme (I don't see a table will be a good solution here) that can easily show what is where ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spend a non-trivial amount of time trying to persuade people to use [dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) for stuff like this.  Not because it's a great diagram-making programme, which it's not (though it's pretty good), but because it runs on Windows, Mac and Linux, so the largest possible group of people can help work on any given diagram.

As a secondary benefit, I can send dia files far and wide, leave them in wikis, or get them to new people in any number of other ways, knowing that whoever comes across them at some future date is likely to be able to read them without having to spend money on a software licence first.

Comment: I want to thank you for introducing dia for me. It's a cooltool. As another question, do you know what are the symbols for Webservice?

Comment: Saariko: you're welcome, and thanks for accepting my answer.  If you're asking whether there's a standard network diagram symbol for a web server, then I'm afraid that if there is I don't know about it.  Anyone else?